# Pandas bar graph plot with different color for each column based on value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I have data in a pandas dataframe with 14 columns. I want to plot their values in the form of a bar graph so it looks something like the image below.
Suppose I have sales data for four different regions per quarter.
[image: bar graph example taken from internet]

I want to change the color of a bar to red for example, if its higher than a certain value. In the above figure, if the sales for a region per quarter are greater then 60k, the corresponding bar in the graph should be red instead of  a shade of blue. I have been able to achieve that when I plot the bar graph for a single column, but not for multiple columns together. I would appreciate if anyone can guide me towards the solution using `dataframe.plot()` or any other `matplotlib` function.
Thanks

Comment: This question would be more answerable with some sample data to generate this plot, your code so far, and details about this threshold and specifics about what should happen when the threshold is exceeded.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @henry-ecker. I have updated my question with more details and an example scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution after a painstaking process of trial and error. The idea is to plot the bar graph normally, and then modify it based on some conditions. Here is a sample code:

```
....
ax = df.plot(x='column_name', ... , color=colors)
for bar in ax.patches:
  if bar.get_height() > some_value:
    bar.set_color('red')
....
```